# get type number from $("#screen").load('banners.php')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, asp-classic

I want to plot data to grafik but very hard how to get number and make variable from `screen`.

```
$("#screen").load('banners.php')
```

For example I want like this

```
var x = // value of screen here
var c = x + 20;
```

How to get value from `screen` and sent to variable? Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: what is going to come and sit in `"#screen"` via call `$("#screen").load('banners.php')`?

Comment: What do you mean `value of screen`? Is it `text()`, `html()`, some `data()` or other attribute? Either way you need to use the callback parameter of `load()`

Comment: Thank You Sir Rory, for example in page1 (banner.asp) i set number 100 and i want to read that number by page2(index.asp). Function to call page1 is $("#variable_here").load('banners.asp') then i show the variable using <div id="variable_here"> </div> is correctly show. But i need get data from "variable_here" and save to other variable because i want to use other variable to make some math function i think simple but hard work for me because always "undefine". May be you have solution sir.....you are expert than me..Thank you very much Sir.